# Does Google Drive have an issue with lots of revisions?

Tags: ms-office, google-drive-api, documents, revisions

Anyone have experience of documents in drive with lots of revisions, all marked as "do not delete"?

I have a customer who has such a scenario and once they get between 150 and 200 revisions for a document they don't seem to be able to upload further revisions - either through the API or the Google Drive Web app.  The documents in question are MS Office docs rather than Google Docs.

Any ideas for work arounds to allow the user to keep updating the documents further or what to do with a document when it gets into that state?﻿

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an undocumented limit of 200 pinned revisions per-file. I've filed a bug with the engineering team to return a better error message. As a workaround, un-pin older revisions.

Comment: Hi Eric thanks for the response.  What's the chances of removing the limit rather than reporting an error?  Otherwise I can see us having to create a new document for each revision and abandoning the use of revisions all together.

Comment: That's likely harder to change, although I can inquire about it. In the mean time you'll need to find a workaround that works for you.